# Surprising features of vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[vscode features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFvKa.png)
Today I saw a very surprising feature of vscode. When browsing functions, the function signature of the current function will be displayed at the top of the editor. This is really useful. I want to know how to set up this feature and in which version it was updated.

I want to know how to set up this feature and in which version it was updated.

Comment: Search the settings for all `editor sticky scroll` settings.